# Is $ \mu(E \times F) \leq \nu(E \times F) \forall (E,F) \implies \mu(A) \leq \nu(A) \forall A \in \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F} $ true?

Tags: measure-theory, inequality

Let $(X,\mathcal{E})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{F})$ denote two measurable spaces and let $\mu,\nu$ denote two **finite** measures on $(X \times Y, \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F})$, where $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}:= \sigma(\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F})$. Consider the claim

$$
\mu(E \times F) \leq \nu(E \times F) \text{ for all } (E,F) \in \mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F} \implies \mu(A) \leq \nu(A) \text{ for all } A \in \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}.
$$

*Question: Is this claim true?*

---

**Attempt:**

Define the set $$
M = \{A \in \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F} \colon \mu(A) \leq \nu(A)\}.
$$
Then we want to show that $M = \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$. Note that clearly $M \subseteq \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$. For the other inclusion, we have by assumption that $\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F} \subseteq M$ so it follows that  $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}= \sigma(\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F}) \subseteq \sigma (M)$ and hence it would suffice to show $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

However I am not sure this is the case. I can't seem to show that $M$ is closed under complements and countable unions. In particular say for the union part, we can do the following:
$$
\mu(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n) \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mu(A_n) \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \nu(A_n),
$$
but then we cannot go back to $\nu(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n)$. So this is where I am stuck.

I have also tried to look at Dynkin's $\pi$-theorem but at least I could not see how this was useful here.

Also I haven't been able to come up with any counterexample yet.

---

As a final remark, I will just need to apply this result for $\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}^d}),\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}^m})$ but I would like to prove it higher generality if this is indeed possible. If this is not possible, are there any conditions we can impose for it to hold? Any feedback/help is much appreciated!

Comment: Isn't $\mu(X)-\mu(A) \leq \mu(X) - \nu(A)$ not true as $\nu(A) \geq \mu(A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $(X,\mathcal{E})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{F})$ denote two **finite** measurable spaces and let $\mu,\nu$ denote two measures on $(X \times Y, \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F})$, where $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}:= \sigma(\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F})$. Then
>
> $$
> \mu(E \times F) \leq \nu(E \times F) \text{ for all } (E,F) \in \mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F} \implies \mu(A) \leq \nu(A) \text{ for all } A \in \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}.
> $$

**Proof**: Suppose $\mu(E \times F) \leq \nu(E \times F) \text{ for all } (E,F) \in \mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F}$.

It is easy to see that $\mu|_{\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F} }$ is a pre-measure on the semi-ring $\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F}$. Let $\mu^*$ be the outer measure induced by $\mu|_{\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F} }$.
In the same way,   $\nu|_{\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F} }$ is a pre-measure on the semi-ring $\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F}$. Let $\nu^*$ be the outer measure induced by $\nu|_{\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F} }$.

Since $\mu(E \times F) \leq \nu(E \times F) \text{ for all } (E,F) \in \mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F}$, it follows immediately that, for all $A \in 2^{X \times Y}$,
$\mu^*(A)\leq \nu^*(A)$.

Now, note that, since $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}:= \sigma(\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F})$, we have that, for all $A \in \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$, $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable (in the sense of Catatheodory's measurability). So $\mu^*|_{\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F} }$ is a measure that extends $\mu|_{\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F} }$. Since $\mu$ is finite, we have that $\mu|_{\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F} }$ is finite and so it has only one extension to $ \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$.
So, for all $A \in \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$,
$\mu^*(A) = \mu (A)$. The same reasoning applies to $\nu$. So, for all $A \in \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$,
$\nu^*(A) = \nu (A)$.

So, we have, for all $A \in \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$,
$$  \mu(A) = \mu^*(A)\leq \nu^*(A) =\nu(A)$$

**Remark**: We don't need the measures to be finite. It is enough to assume that $\mu|_{\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F} }$ and $\nu|_{\mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{F} }$  are $\sigma$-finite. This assumption is enough to assure that they have unique extensions to $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: This looks very nice but I have some follow up questions: 
You are using Catatheodory's extension theorem right for the induced outer measure, right? How do we know this coincides with the measure itself (not the pre-measure) on $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$?
Also it seems we are not using that the measures are finite, does it not? So the hypothesis can in fact be strengthened.

Comment: @Jacobiman , Yes, I am using Catatheodory's extension theorem.  We know this coincides with the measure itself on $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$ exactly because the measures are finite. It is where we use the fact that the measures are finite. I have added an paragraph explaining step by step this point. I have also added a remark at end on how we could partly relax the condition that the two measures be finite.